# Single-use variables: can you ensure each enum member is only referenced once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm working on a React app written in Typescript.

I want to give each of 100+ components a unique ID that remains constant over user sessions:

```html
<Component id={"ID_1"} />
<Component id={"ID_2"} />
```

No two components should ever be assigned the same ID.

At the moment, I'm using a TypeScript enum to keep track, but there's nothing stopping me, or a colleague, from accidentally assigning the same enum member to two components:

```html
enum Ids = {
  Id1,
  Id2,
}

<Component id={Ids.Id1}/>
<Component id={Ids.Id1}/> // oops
```

Does anyone know of a way to ensure that an enum member (or other variable) is only referenced once, across an entire codebase, at compile time?

I've wondered if this can be achieved using an ESLint rule but can't find any examples of ESLint counting references across an entire codebase? It also feels like this could get really slow with the linter running live as you type.

Comment: You can create your own [ESLint plugin](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins), but as you say, if you're not careful coding it (caching counts for untouched files, etc.) it could get very slow.

Comment: You could use regex and write your own build step tool.  Scan all source files (limited to specific extensions) searching for `<Component ... />`, gather them all together, then make sure none are duped.

Comment: I mean, okay, but why? are uuids not sufficient? and why do they need system managed IDs if you're not going to automate the ID assignment?

Comment: @DavidCulbreth The IDs must remain constant across sessions (it's for saving settings related to each component) so calling a UUID generator at runtime wouldn't work